# How to have a functioning "Select All" checkbox?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, checkbox

I have a functioning Select All checkbox that removes all the items in the Accounts List when clicked, however, the UI isn't displaying that the items in the list are clicked, how can I update the UI so that the checkboxes on the Accounts List will also get checked along with the Select All when I click on it.

I have 2 files, the first file will be the one containing all the logic of the "Select All" checkbox and the List of the Accounts itself, the 2nd file would be where we can locate the checkboxes of the list.

**File 1 (where the Select All Checkbox and the Logic of the Select All can be found)**

```
class SwitchAccountDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  const SwitchAccountDrawer({
    Key? key,
    required this.user,
    required this.dashboardBloc,
    required this.screenName,
    required this.inventoryUpdateLatUpdatedDate,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final UserModel? user;
  final DashboardBloc dashboardBloc;
  final String screenName;
  final String inventoryUpdateLatUpdatedDate;

  @override
  State<SwitchAccountDrawer> createState() => SwitchAccountDrawerState();
}

class SwitchAccountDrawerState extends State<SwitchAccountDrawer> {
  final SecureStorageUtil _ssu = SecureStorageUtil();
  bool _showCheckbox = false;
  bool _showSelectAll = false;
  bool isAllSelected = false;
  bool isSelected = false;

  late List<dynamic> sessionList;
  late List<String?> selectedUsers;

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchSavedSessions();
    sessionList = [];
    selectedUsers = [];

    super.initState();
  }

  void fetchSavedSessions() async {
    print("savedSessions start");
    String savedSessions = await _ssu.getValue(Strings.savedSessions) ?? '';
    if (savedSessions.isNotEmpty) {
      print("savedSessions $savedSessions");
      setState(() {
        sessionList = jsonDecode(savedSessions)
            .where((i) => i['userId'] != widget.user?.id)
            .toList();
      });
      print("savedSessions sessionList $sessionList ");
      print("savedSessions count ${sessionList.length}");
    } else {
      setState(() {
        sessionList = [];
      });
      print("savedSessions NO SAVED ACCOUNTS");
    }
  }

  void _toggleAllSelection(bool isSelected) {
    setState(() {
      isAllSelected = isSelected;
      if (isAllSelected) {
        selectedUsers = sessionList
            .map<String?>((session) => session['userId'] as String?)
            .toList();
      } else {
        selectedUsers.clear();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 220,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                DrawerHeader(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 36),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: AppColors.staticBlue,
                  ),
                  child: Image.asset('assets/images/user_info_bg.png'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                _showCheckbox
                    ? "Manage Accounts on this Device"
                    : "Switch Account",
                style: TextStyle(
                  letterSpacing: 0.5,
                  fontSize: 17,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  fontFamily: 'HenrySans',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Divider(
            indent: 0,
            endIndent: 0,
            color: AppColors.separatorDashboard,
            height: 1,
            thickness: 1,
          ),
          Visibility(
            visible: _showSelectAll,
            child: CheckboxListTile(
              title: Text("Select All",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontFamily: 'HenrySans',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  )),
              controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
              value: isSelected,
              onChanged: (bool? value) {
                setState(() {
                  isSelected = value ?? false;
                  isAllSelected = value ?? false;
                  if (isSelected && isAllSelected) {
                    selectedUsers = sessionList
                        .map((session) => session['userId'] as String?)
                        .toList();
                  } else {
                    selectedUsers.clear();
                  }
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          ListView.builder(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              itemCount: sessionList.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                print("WIDGET USER LV ${sessionList[index]["userInfo"]}");
                return AccountTile(
                  session: sessionList[index],
                  user: sessionList[index]["userInfo"],
                  dashboardBloc: widget.dashboardBloc,
                  store: '',
                  showCheckbox: _showCheckbox,
                  onCheckChanged: (id, isChecked) {
                    index =
                        selectedUsers.indexWhere((String? user) => user == id);
                    print("123 Hello $index");
                    if (index < 0 && isChecked!) {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedUsers.add(id);
                      });
                    } else {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedUsers.removeAt(index);
                      });
                    }
                    setState(() {});
                    print("123 Hello $id $isChecked");
                  },
                );
              }),
```

**File 2 (where the Checkboxes for the Account Tile can be found)**

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:sm_store_admin/core/presentation/model/user_model.dart';
import 'package:sm_store_admin/core/presentation/utils/constants/app_color.dart';
import 'package:sm_store_admin/core/presentation/utils/string_extension.dart';
import 'package:sm_store_admin/features/common/confirmation_dialog.dart';
import 'package:sm_store_admin/features/contact_us/contact_us_screen.dart';
import 'package:sm_store_admin/features/dashboard/bloc/dashboard_bloc.dart';
import 'package:sm_store_admin/features/dashboard/data/dashboard_screen_args.dart';
import 'package:sm_store_admin/features/dashboard/presentation/screens/dashboard_screen.dart';
import 'package:sm_store_admin/features/login/bloc/login_bloc.dart';
import 'package:sm_store_admin/features/login/presentation/screens/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:sm_store_admin/features/user_information/presentation/screens/user_information_screen.dart';

enum PopUpMenuChoices { removeAccount, manageAccount }

class AccountTile extends StatefulWidget {
  const AccountTile({
    Key? key,
    required this.user,
    required this.session,
    required this.dashboardBloc,
    required this.store,
    required this.showCheckbox,
    required this.onCheckChanged,
    this.showSelectAll = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Map<String, dynamic> user;
  final Map<String, dynamic> session;
  final DashboardBloc dashboardBloc;
  final String store;
  final bool showCheckbox;
  final bool showSelectAll;

  final Function(String? id, bool? isChecked) onCheckChanged;

  @override
  State<AccountTile> createState() => AccountTileState();
}

class AccountTileState extends State<AccountTile> {
  bool isSelected = false;
  bool _showCheckbox = false;
  bool isAllSelected = false;
  bool _showSelectAll = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _showCheckbox = widget.showCheckbox;
    _showSelectAll = widget.showSelectAll;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<LoginBloc>(
        create: (BuildContext context) => LoginBloc(),
        child: Column(children: [
          Visibility(
            visible: widget.showSelectAll,
            child: Checkbox(
              value: isAllSelected,
              onChanged: (bool? value) {
                widget.onCheckChanged(widget.user['id'], value);
                setState(() {
                  isAllSelected = value ?? false;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          ListTile(
              onTap: () async {
                await LoginBloc().changeUserSession(
                    widget.session["sessionToken"],
                    widget.session["userInfo"],
                    widget.session["refreshToken"]);

                Navigator.pop(context);
                Navigator.of(context).push(LoginScreen.route(true));
              },
              title: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 0, 15),
                height: 65,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: isSelected
                        ? Border.all(color: AppColors.primaryColor)
                        : Border.all(color: Colors.black12),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Visibility(
                      visible: widget.showCheckbox,
                      child: Checkbox(
                        value: isSelected,
                        onChanged: (bool? value) {
                          widget.onCheckChanged(widget.user['id'], value);
                          setState(() {
                            isSelected = value ?? false;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            '${widget.user["firstName"]}',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              letterSpacing: 0.5,
                              fontSize: 14,
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              fontFamily: 'HenrySans',
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    PopupMenuExample()
                  ],
                ),
              ))
        ]));
  }
}

class PopupMenuExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const PopupMenuExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PopupMenuExample> createState() => _PopupMenuExampleState();
}

class _PopupMenuExampleState extends State<PopupMenuExample> {
  PopUpMenuChoices? selectedMenu;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopupMenuButton<PopUpMenuChoices>(
      initialValue: selectedMenu,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      onSelected: (PopUpMenuChoices item) {
        print("itemitem $item");
        setState(() {
          selectedMenu = item;
        });
      },
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry<PopUpMenuChoices>>[
        const PopupMenuItem<PopUpMenuChoices>(
          value: PopUpMenuChoices.removeAccount,
          child: Text('Remove Account'),
        ),
        const PopupMenuItem<PopUpMenuChoices>(
          value: PopUpMenuChoices.manageAccount,
          child: Text('Manage Account'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I'm very new to Flutter as I've only started learning about it months ago therefore I don't have that much experience when it comes to the UI and Logic, if there's any confusion, I'd be more than happy to explain and provide the missing code if there's any.

Thanks!